# How do I can fix this problem of indented block?

Tags: python, telethon, forward

This code does not work - I need help. I want to re-send a specific message.

```
@events.register(events.NewMessage(chats='AAAAA'))
async def me_handler(event):
  client = event.client
if 'AAAAAAAA' in event.raw_text:
 async def main(event):
 await event.forward_to('AAAAA')
```

Expected an indented block

Comment: It might be due to your `await event.forward_to('AAAAA')` as it's not indented within `def main()`  Indent that line and try again.

Comment: done 




`if 'AAAAAAAA' in event.raw_text:
  async def main(event):
   await event.forward_to('SSSSSSS')`

but indeed not work and not gib me error just not re-send the message

Comment: Why no return anything. I don't know need some more insight regarding code.

Comment: It is a code that I want it to detect when a specific message enters a bot and that message is forwarded by the code to another bot in telegram

Comment: Could you fix the indentation of your code?

Answer (score 0):

You need an extra indent after `async def main(event):`:

```py
@events.register(events.NewMessage(chats='AAAAA'))
async def me_handler(event):
    client = event.client

if 'AAAAAAAA' in event.raw_text:
    async def main(event):
        await event.forward_to('AAAAA')
```

Additionally, is is recommended by [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#indentation) to use 4 spaces per indent. I found your code harder to read with such little indentation.

Comment: I already applied that measure and it does not give me an indentation error but it does not perform the operation, it runs without errors but it does not forward the message

Comment: It is a code that I want it to detect when a specific message enters a bot and that message is forwarded by the code to another bot in telegram

Comment: The original question doesn't mention anything about telegram or bots, just the indentation error. I suggest you create another question with those details, what's your objective and which libraries are you using.

Comment: You seem inexperienced with python - if so, I'd suggest to start with some tutorials before.

Comment: hi thanks the code is fixed:


`@events.register(events.NewMessage(chats='AAAAA'))
async def me_handler(event):
    client = event.client

if 'AAAAAAAA' in event.raw_text:
        await event.forward_to('AAAAA')`